# Excel: максимальное значение столбца содержащено #VALUE!

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

В таблице есть столбец содержащий числа. Но в этом столбце есть одно-два значения #VALUE!. Из-за этого функция MAX на этом столбце выдаёт #VALUE!. Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить максимальное значение из корректных числовых значений в этом столбце?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обхода ошибок, сокрытий и т.п. имеется функция АГРЕГАТ(), в англоязычной версии AGGREGATE().

В описанном случае, вероятно, достаточно ссылочной версии функции листа. Например

```
=АГРЕГАТ(4;6;A1:A10)
```

См. напр. [WorksheetFunction.Aggregate Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-aggregate-method-excel) или [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df).

Comment: Ваше решение подошло. Только у меня англоязычная версия и разделитель между аргументами функции должен быть , а не ;.
Моя формула: =AGGREGATE(4,6,D$2:D$281)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать формулу [массива](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):
Например, так:

```
{=МАКС(ЕСЛИОШИБКА($A$1:$A$5;""))}
```

P.S. Ставится черз CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 0):

Вариант:

```
=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(A2:A99);;A2:A8))
```

Формула массива, водится тремя клавишами *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*

Если значения в диапазоне по возрастанию, можно простой формулой искать последнее числовое значение:

```
=ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;A2:A99)
```

А вообще, правильно: не допускать появления на листе ошибок - обходить ее в формуле, которая выводит значения в этом диапазоне. Если данные подтянуты извне (без формул), выделить диапазон и инструменом *НАЙТИ/ЗАМЕНИТЬ* удалить ошибки.